# Binding to @ConfigurationProperties with a Map does not preserve the order of keys

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using @ConfigurationProperties to inject the map from properties file. Below is the code:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("product")
public class WebUtils {
private WebUtils() {
}

public static String getURLWithContextPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
            + request.getContextPath();
}

private static Map<String, String> solitaireProp = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Map<String, String> getSolitaireProp() {
    return solitaireProp;
}

public static List<String> getSolitaireProperties(){
    List<String> solProp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : solitaireProp.entrySet()) {
        solProp.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    return solProp;
}}
```

The code is working fine but it is not preserving the order of entries I have in the properties file e.g. if properties file enter is:

```
product.solitaireProp.lab=lab
product.solitaireProp.certificateNo=certificate_number
product.solitaireProp.shape=shape
```

But the entries to my LinkedHashMap is not in same order as above. Do anyone know how to maintain the order??

Answer (score 1):

Properties (with or without Spring Boot) are not designed to maintain any specific order.
If maintaining order matters, don't use classical Properties but use your own way to read the file and to maintain the order of the elements in the file.
As alternative you could rewrite the way to load the Properties but it is really a burden, overall if you use Spring Boot feature to load the Properties as you would have very few possibilities to override the loading processing.